# Where do thrown errors in Javascript land in a web app?

Tags: javascript, html, exception, web-applications

So, I was trying to decide how to handle errors in a complicated TS / JS library I am writing. I was looking at actually throwing errors and letting them bubble up the stack, but in a web application using JS, I am not sure actually where the 'top' level catch should be.

I am using HTML5 + Javascript + jQuery to write a single page app that dynamically loads and unloads modules as needed, so I have in theory a single deffinite entry point. (either the jQuery '$(function() {})', or the window.onload() method)

Once things start rolling though, I don't think user triggered events generating errors would bubble up to here. I did some research, and there is a window.onerror method handler that might intercept an uncaught error.

I am concerned about using thrown errors as a solution, because an uncaught error will crash the application according to the docs I have read. Not sure what that means in the context of a client side web script (JS thread termination for that page + nasty popup?)

In non-web apps, there is typically a way to register a global error handler
to catch all the pokimon exceptions. I have never seen anything like that for JS, does it exist?

If I go this route, where is the best place to catch all the unhandled errors that I generate? Alternately, is this just a bad idea to try to use application model exception handling on a web app?

Comment: It depends on whether the console is open, and if it's open there's a setting that says what to do with uncaught errors.

Comment: If you don't have the console open and set to stop on uncaught errors, it simply unwinds the entire call stack and returns back to the browser's event loop.

Comment: So it's as if every event handler had `try { ... } catch (e) { return; }` around it.

Comment: Are you referring to using throw without a catch block?. If there is a catch block then the program will return to the catch block and everything will run from there... however if you throw and there is no catch block wrapping it, then the program will terminate. I have never used throw without a try catch block, but I can only assume that yes

Comment: @Jony-Y I think he's talking about errors that are thrown internally by Javascript (like undefined variable), but it doesn't really matter what throws them.

Comment: Indeed. You don't write error management code for someone sitting on a debugger!